# Angular — Route params in service returns null

Tags: angular, service

I'm desperately trying to get the route params from a service so when I access a section from the url, I can detect the section's id and load it in this service.

The route path is 'sections/:section' with children. This gives a URL like this: /sections/2/home

I tried to use the following:

```
this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {params.get('section');});
```

But it returns "null"...

I also tried other options but it returned an empty string :/

Any ideas? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Can you show some code. Where you are calling it and how you are navigating

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm out of the office so I can't post the whole thing... I'm trying to subscribe when the service is instantiated in constructor() {
this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {params.get("section");});
}

Comment: here is an example i created on router params : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vcab7e

Comment: So, from a component I managed to get it. But not from a service :/

Comment: Because the `ActivatedRoute` object is heirarchical, it is tough to get what you are looking for from a service. If you look at your `this.route`, you will notice that it has children routes. What you are looking for is buried in the children routes somewhere. You have to look through that tree to find it. It is confusing and really drives me crazy. Sorry you are being frustrated by this. It frustrates a lot of people, FYI.

Comment: If you pass the `ActivatedRoute` from your component into the service, the service can then access it. Otherwise, the service will get the root-level `ActivatedRoute`, which means that you will need to look through the tree to find what you are looking for. Cheers.

Comment: So instead of getting it in the service, you can get it in the component and pass it to the service. What is your flow so we can help you with it?

Comment: That's a shame, I was hoping I could have a "single" trigger from a single element (my service)... So far the only solution I found was to push the route param from a component to the service and them call the data accordingly.

But I feel that it's not very efficient and I couldn't find anything working on the web :/

Answer (score 0):

Specify the router path as,
`{path: 'resetpassword/:token', component: ForgotPasswordComponent}`

```
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
  this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.userdetails=params.token;
  });
}
```